# How does requestScope object of Expression Language work in a JSP file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

So I have this simple code in a jsp file:

```
${requestScope.getClass()}
```

which returns me:

```
class javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ScopeManager$9
```

which makes me think this object is of type ImplicitObjectELResolver. (I may be wrong even here..)

Well, when I look at the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/el/ImplicitObjectELResolver.html) for this nice class: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver
, I see:

> Defines variable resolution behavior for the EL implicit objects
>   defined in the JSP specification.
>
> The following variables are resolved by this ELResolver, as per the
>   JSP specification:
>
> pageContext - the PageContext object. pageScope - a Map that maps page-scoped attribute names to their values.
>
> requestScope - a Map that maps request-scoped attribute names to their values.

Now I am confused because here I am thinking I already have the an object of type *Map*. But the object I have is supposed to have a variable called *requestScope* which is a Map..

So what actually happens when I call

```
${requestScope.firstName}
```

for example?

Am I calling getKey("firstName") on a Map object, or is something else going on?

Comment: The object is of type `javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ScopeManager$9`. That is an anonymous inner class of the nested class `ScopeManager` of the class `ImplicitObjectELResolver`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSP servlet, as part of the EL resolution, will use the `ImplicitObjectELResolver` to resolve the name `requestScope`. That resolution consists in invoking `getRequestScopeMap()` which returns an anonymous inner class of type `EnumeratedMap<String, Object>` which has access to all attributes in the request scope.

Once that `EnumeratedMap` is return, the EL resolution will continue by trying to invoke the `Map`'s `get(..)` method with the given name in the EL expression. For example, the name is `firstName` in

```
${requestScope.firstName}
```

---

The implementation may have changed from version to version.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, so I might be off here, but I think EL looks at the type of an object several ways before deciding how to interpret your property there.  So if you make a call ("`getClass()`") and that method exists, the call is made.  Otherwise, EL might go looking for a Map if it didn't find the `getClass()` method.

Also, just because the class name is `javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ScopeManager$9` doesn't mean that class can't also implement an interface like `Map`.  I'd guess it probably does.  But it's still a class with all the methods from `Object`, as well as I'm sure probably several methods of its own, in additions to the Map interface.

Edit:

`ScopeManager` isn't a Map, but almost all of its methods return a map.  Check out the [reverse engineered docs I found.](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/el/ImplicitObjectELResolver$ScopeManager.html)

Comment: This confuses me: Otherwise, EL might go looking for a Map if it didn't find the getClass() method.

Comment: I'm just saying the compiler could look at an object reflectively and determine its type, before deciding how to look up a property.  It wouldn't be that hard to write such a method yourself.  I've done stuff similar for some debugging code I wrote.